# Moving Virtual Box VMs from Windows to Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have some web sites running on a Windows 2008 Server VM. The host is Windows.
Is it possible to move the Windows Server to a Linux VB host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the virtual environment the VMs are in stays the same (for e.g. moving VirtualBox on PC1 to VirtualBox on PC2), it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: I've done this the other way and it worked just fine.